# Automatic login to Website when User login to Facebook based on cookie

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph Toolkit and developing ASP.NET website.

I want to create and design a website that has registration that will use a Facebook account as an alternative to my website login/registration.

I am thinking of just storing the Facebook User ID who has approved the use of the FB app in order to identify the user for next time when he/she logs in to my website using his Facebook account.

Scenario here is:

1. Any browser, user already logged in to his Facebook account (say browser Tab no.1).
2. Same browser, Tab no.2, user visits my website (he has already registered to my website using his Facebook account, as I store his Facebook ID).
3. Upon his visit to my website home page, the top corner will display his account name (this indicates that he has logged in to my website even though he has only logged in to Facebook, but never visited my website and clicked on the Login button).

So my question is, how to achieve the scenario of step no.3?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy but you need to do some research first. Research will better help you to understand each and every point.
Go to the [Facebook Developers API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and do some reading.

Comment: That's a little condescending, don't you think?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. I respect your point of view. But I am insisting him to research rather then waiting for someone to give him whole code. That's Why I said that. Ok even I have edited my answer. Now is it right?

Comment: Better, certainly.  I resisted the temptation to add "If you still have questions afterwards, come back and ask again, showing us what you've tried, explaining what it is doing or not doing, and asking for assistance".

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. Thanks for your guidelines. I will better care of it in future

Comment: Condescending plus should be a comment and not actually an answer